# Timestamp variations between oracle and postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, timezone, timestamp

Currently, I am working on migrating an Oracle database schema to Postgres. As part of it I have to convert a custom utility function in Oracle which generates timestamps based on timezone. But the values obtained from Oracle and Postgres seem to vary by one hour.

Oracle:

```
SELECT (to_timestamp_tz('20300714 235959 CET','YYYYMMDD HH24MISS TZR') - to_timestamp_tz('19700101 000000 GMT','YYYYMMDD HH24MISS TZR'))
    as foo FROM dual;
```

yields **+22109 21:59:59.000000**

Postgres:

```
select ('20300714 235959'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET') - ('19700101 000000'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'GMT') as foo;
```

yields **22109 days 22:59:59**

I guess the reason for this difference is because of daylight saving but I am not sure. Can anyone help me out with this problem.
I am using Postgres v9.6 and Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the mistake I was doing. Postgres seems to handle the abbreviated timezone name and full timezone name differently. In case if you want to incorporate daylight related changes you would have to use full timezone name. In my case using 'Europe/Amsterdam' instead of 'CET' yielded the same result as that of Oracle.
To find the complete list of full timezone names supported by Postgres, I used the query:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names where abbrev='CET';
```